# Can't move mouse cursor

Tags: windows, mouse, mouse-cursor

When I turn my PC on, my mouse cursor is freezed, I can't move it to any direction, but all buttons are working and the leds are on. First I thought my mouse had broken because if I test it on another PC the same thing happens: cursor freezes and buttons work.

BUT when I change  a couple of times  the USB port my mouse it's plugged in(sometimes I have to do it like, 3, 4, 5 times) it starts to work normal, perfectly.

I tried everything to solve this... Reinstalled M712 software, I restored the mouse  config, cleaned all reg, I even reinstalled Windows and it still happens.

Model: Redragon Octopus M712
Windows 10 Pro 64 (V. 1909)

I5 9600k
Motherboard Gigabyte Z390M Gaming
16gb Ram
EVGA Gtx 1070
Powersupply Corsair VS650W

Comment: Are you plugged into a HUB?  This can be problematic.  Try going direct with devices that don't work well through hubs.  I myself am using a Rosewill NEON M62.. I sometimes have to unplug and replug to get it to respond.

Comment: no, it's direct plugged into the motherboard

Comment: Looks like not a common problem for this mouse.  Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: Yes, they told me my mouse is under warranty, but I can't found its box so I hope I could solve this issue. it's weird because it started happening suddenly, I used this mouse for like 3"  months